# Error in aggregate.data.frame : arguments must have same length

Tags: r, aggregate

I keep getting this error and I'm not quite sure what it means. All of my variable names are consistent and there are no typos. Am I missing something here?

The code

```
datNewagg <- aggregate (dataNew, by = list('x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'ab'), 
                                                             FUN = mean)
```

Produces the error

```
  Error in aggregate.data.frame(datNew, by = list("x", "y",  : 
  arguments must have same length
```

Comment: Can you dput the exact datafame?

Comment: Can you show the `aggregate` call, as it mat be incorrectly specified. ty

Comment: You get a similar error with `aggregate(mtcars, list("am"), mean)`. But if you specify it like `aggregate(mtcars, list(mtcars$am), mean)` or 
`aggregate(. ~ am , mean, data=mtcars)` everything is okay

Comment: `datNewagg <- aggregate (dataNew, by = list('x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'ab'), FUN = mean)`

Comment: ok, have a look at the comment above on specifying aggregate function. . Try `datNewagg <- aggregate (. ~ x + y + z + a + ab), FUN = mean, data=dataNew)` or `datNewagg <- with(dataNew, aggregate (dataNew, by = list(x, y, z, a, ab), FUN = mean))`

Answer (score 15):

Assuming it's not a typo (the data frame is called `dataNew` in your call but `datNew` in the error), are `x`, `y`, `z`, `a` and `ab` the names of columns in `dataNew`?

Some functions, like [`subset`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/subset), will allow you to specify column names of the object they're working on directly. The [`aggregate`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/aggregate) function doesn't, so any columns of `dataNew` listed in the `by` argument need to specifically referred to as such. Try this:

```
datNewagg <- aggregate(dataNew,
    by = list(
        x = dataNew$x,
        y = dataNew$y,
        z = dataNew$z,
        a = dataNew$a,
        ab = dataNew$ab),
    FUN = mean)
```

Answer (score 12):

I used get this error.
The simple solution to remove this error is to write all the variables along with their dataset name like "ds_name$var_name".
I'm not sure what is the dataset name is your case, so I'll give you another similar example.

```
curYearRev <-aggregate(hr$Year.Total, by = list(hr$Hospital_ID,hr$District_ID,hr$Instrument_ID) , FUN = sum)
```

Here, "hr" is the dataset name and "Year.Total", "Hospital_ID", "District_ID", "Instrument_ID" are the variables in "hr" dataset.

Writing aggregate functions in this way will never give you any errors again.

Answer (score 1):

Check `class(dataNew)`. If it's not a data.frame, this `dataNew <- data.frame(dataNew)` before aggregation should solve the error or

```
datNewagg <- aggregate (data.frame(dataNew), by = list('x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'ab'), 
                                                         FUN = mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `with(...,aggregate(...))` don't put your column names in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.frame` as `by` argument works for me
try this:

```
datNewagg <- aggregate (dataNew, by = dataNew[c('x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'ab')],                                                             FUN = mean)
```

I mean don't give the `by` argument, just the name of the arguments, give a data.frame with columns as these arguments